# How can I get Chrome to stop killing my tabs in the background?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I have a chat page open at https://app.purechat.com/quick-links and after a few hours, I come back to the page and Chrome reloads it because it has killed it in the background. The app thinks that I am offline and I am not getting chat notifications. How can I stop Chrome from killing the tab it is loaded in? I have 32GB.

Comment: Have you tried pinning the tab? (Right-click on tab, click "Pin tab") If I remember correctly pinned tabs were originally meant for background apps, but I'm not sure if Google stuck with that vision or not. It's worth a try.

Comment: Chrome is not killing your tab, its hibernating it, to consume memory. See also: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/tab-discarding

Comment: @3D1T0R OK I pinned it. But then it moves it to the far left, while I normally keep my development environment on tab `CTRL+1` and the chat in `CTRL+4`.

Comment: @LPChip: According to that page Chrome *is* killing it: "What do we mean by discarding? ... We kill it but it's still visible on the Chrome tab strip." however it also points to a solution for @​Chloe: "A new page called chrome://discards lets you list what tabs are currently open and we try to share some insight into how interesting (we think) they are to you, from most to least." From that description it may not *seem* like a solution, but going to there in current versions of Chrome gives me a list of tabs it might discard, and offers a "toggle" option to prevent discarding certain tabs.

Comment: @Chloe: According to my (limited) testing, pinning the tab does prevent it from being automatically discarded.

Comment: @3D1T0R Isn't it obvious that 32GB refers to RAM? The asker is surely saying, "I have plenty of RAM so Chrome doesn't need to junk this tab to save memory." 32GB of disc space would be pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Yes & No. It's obvious to someone who knows computers inside and out that that's what it *should* be referring to, but those of us answering questions on SE sites don't necessarily know how much experience with computers an asker has, and there's a chance (for all I know) that @​Chloe is using a netbook with a 32GB SSD and is saying "I have 32GB." because they bought "the 32GB model" of that particular netbook & didn't realize that it has very little RAM. (Note: I'm not saying that's the case, but without clarification from the OP, we don't *actually* know.)

Comment: @3D1T0R I would say that the amount of the type memory is actually irrelevant either way as any decent operating system will use the harddrive to swap in and out any inactive memory pages. so really this is just a matter of telling Chrome to not kill the tab. If the computer runs out of memory and Chrome *itself* crashed that's somewhat tangential to the current issue. Let's fix Chrome force reloading a page and go from there. Yes each Chrome tab is a process but the process isn't crashing. The Chrome window is refreshing it. That's not a memory issue and irrelevant to any future readers.

Comment: @3D1T0R 32GB of "don't really want to talk about it"

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: Not if there's not enough space to do so, or if it's been configured not to. Though this is all beside the point. The point is that there's ambiguity in the question which should be clarified by the asker, not argued about in the comments.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

### Alternative 1

To stop Chrome from reloading pages when you return to them after they have been in the background:

1. Enter the following into your Chrome address bar:
   `chrome://flags/`
2. Search for the "Automatic tab discarding" flag
3. Set it to "Disabled"

You may also want to set the "Offline Auto-Reload Mode" flag to "Disabled".

---

### Alternative 2

If you don't want to disable Automatic tab discarding for *all* the tabs, alternatively, you also have the option to discard select tabs manually via `chrome://discards`.

On that page, if you have automatic tab discarding still enabled, you can click "Toggle" next to any tab to prevent it from being discarded automatically.

---

### Alternative 3

Pinning the tab will also prevent it from being automatically discarded, however, the pinned tab is moved to the far left which may be unacceptable behavior (particularly for those who use keyboard shortcuts to navigate through their first few tabs). Pinned tabs are also smaller than regular tabs.

---

## References:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/tab-discarding
https://www.guidingtech.com/stop-chrome-reloading-tabs-automatically-switching/
https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/10-hidden-chrome-settings-changing/

Comment: Can you add the bit about `chrome://discards` and the `Auto Discardable Toggle` link? No one wants to disable the feature for _all_ the tabs.

Comment: Regarding Option 1, I do not have that chrome flag on my chrome://flags page. Any idea why? I am on Chrome 68.

Comment: Regarding the third option, do [Ctrl+1](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en) etc. work for switching to pinned tabs?

Comment: Does Chrome also discard "tabs" that are opened in a custom window (as done with `Menu > More tools > Create shortcut... > Check "Open as Window"`? It would explain why Discord is not creating any notifications anymore for me after having that window minimized for some time.

Comment: Alternative 2 is not working. It still discards my tabs and reloads them when I come back, even though I turned the toggle off for that tab.

Comment: Alternative 3 also doesn't work. Version 104.0.5112.101 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 8):

I was able to go to `chrome://discards/` from the link in the comments and toggle a setting on the tab to prevent it from being killed.

[image]

Comment: Does this persist after exiting and reopening Chrome? or do you have to toggle it each time you launch Chrome?

Comment: @3D1T0R On my version of chrome (68.0.3440.106 - 64-bit) across a relaunch (from the flags page's "Relaunch" button) the toggle did **_not_** stay disabled

Comment: Then you may be better off just pinning the tab, as that persists to the next time you launch Chrome (as long as you don't close the window it's pinned in prior to exiting Chrome, e.g. close that window last, or use Menu > Exit or Ctrl+Shift+Q to quit).

Comment: This doesn't actually work. Even when toggled off, it still discards the tab.

Answer (score 7):

This is no longer in the flags and is a full feature in the Chrome settings called "Memory saver"

[image]

More details here: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/12929150?#memory_saver

Comment: Chrome makes this hard to find, but it's a relief to finally discover this.

Comment: What's the syntax of these exceptions? https://superuser.com/questions/1824296/whats-the-syntax-of-url-exceptions-in-chromes-always-keep-these-sites-active