# What's the syntax of URL exceptions in Chrome's "Always keep these sites active"?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium, browser-tabs, tabs

[image]

I want to keep certain tabs from ever being discarded automatically by Chrome. The settings have a section for doing so, but the syntax of the exceptions is not clear. Should I use regexes? Globs? Should `https://` be included? ...

Will this setting be reflected in `chrome://discards/`? Because my Gmail tabs show as discardable even with the exception I have added.
[image]

Related:

- [How can I get Chrome to stop killing my tabs in the background?](https://superuser.com/questions/1353931/how-can-i-get-chrome-to-stop-killing-my-tabs-in-the-background)
- [Stop Chrome from unloading pinned tabs](https://superuser.com/questions/1273166/stop-chrome-from-unloading-pinned-tabs?rq=1)
- [How to force Chrome to keep tabs in memory?](https://superuser.com/questions/1632838/how-to-force-chrome-to-keep-tabs-in-memory)
- [Can you keep a Chrome tab always active every time you go to a specific site?](https://superuser.com/questions/1765335/can-you-keep-a-chrome-tab-always-active-every-time-you-go-to-a-specific-site)
- https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/12929150

Comment: Have you tried from your last link using "Keep specific sites active - Add current sites" to let Chrome write the exception for you?

Answer (score 1):

Source: [Personalize Chrome performance - Google Chrome Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/12929150#zippy=%2Ckeep-specific-sites-active)

The web address format for the manual site exclusion policy is: `[scheme://][.]host[:port][/path][@query]`.

Here are some examples of how to add sites manually if you want to create an exclusion for:

- **Entire domains and subdomains:** Exclude the URL scheme. For example, `google.com` matches and prevents deactivation of subdomains like `drive.google.com` and `calendar.google.com`.
- **Specific domains, but not any subdomains:** Include a dot (.) before the URL host. For example, `.google.com` won't match and prevent deactivation of subdomains like `www.google.com`, `drive.google.com`, and `calendar.google.com`.
- **Specific subdirectory:** Include the URL path. For example, `www.google.com/finance` matches and prevents deactivation of all Google Finance pages, but won't prevent deactivation of the `www.google.com=` =main pages.
- **URL host and query components:** **Asterisks (**) can be used as wildcards. For example, `https://*` matches and prevents deactivation of all https sites and `youtube.com/watch?v=*` matches and prevents deactivation of YouTube videos.

  - Wildcards for prefix, suffix, or substring matches of the URL host component aren't supported. For example, `*oogle.com` or `google.com/*` won't match and prevent deactivation.